# android app Using Flow/coroutine on top of Rxjava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I want to use coroutine in my kotlin app for must of it. but this app depends a lot on a service which return rxjava2 type object (so our input will be all the rxjava type). How can we still use coroutine in this model app instead of rxjava2. should we create a layer only convert rxjava object to normal object (or coroutine object?). or can we use both two together like:

```
   SomeObservable
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe { value->
     viewmodelScope.launch{ 
            // send a flow or coroutine suspend fonction with value
    }
   },
```

Thanks,

Comment: you can convert rx to coroutines/flows https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive

Comment: so if I understand this layer has been already built as in this library

Comment: nice info @IR42, thanks

Comment: no, it's coroutine to rx, I want rx to coroutine

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the RxJava functions with suspend functions.

See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/869

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my own question, It's not a good approche to use flow and rx at the same time. because it resolves the same problem. Rxjava + livedata is a clean architecture to go. or just use flow. so for resume:

- Rxjava + livedata (a little bit coroutine to do some general
  operation)
- flow + coroutine

Two clean ways to make a good architecture. so if I have already rx type there is no need to convert to flow and reuse.